# Using fread() to read multiple records

Tags: c, file-handling

Following is my code for inserting data into file

Note: I have one structure named `record` for that

```
fwrite(&record, sizeof(record),1,fptr);
```

I use the above code in a loop, to enter multiple records.
Now,  I have my data reading program as this:

```
do {
fread(&record, sizeof(record), 1, fptr);
printf("\nName: %s \nAddress: %s \nClass Level: %d \nTelepone: %ld",record.name, record.address, record.classlevel, record.telephone);
}while (feof(fptr));
```

But it only displays only first record.

I also tried using `fseek()` for that as follows:

```
do {
fread(&record, sizeof(record), 1, fptr);
printf("\nName: %s \nAddress: %s \nClass Level: %d \nTelepone: %ld",record.name, record.address, record.classlevel, record.telephone);
fseek(fptr,sizeof(record)+1, SEEK_SET);
}while (feof(fptr));
```

And Still It didn't work!! I am trying to do an small project on C and This File Handling is just getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this:

```
while (feof(fptr))
```

to this:

```
while (!feof(fptr))
```